# Java Method Declaration using < and >

Tags: java

In FindBugs source code, I found this method:

```
package edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba;
....

public class ClassContext {

    ....

    private <Analysis> Analysis getMethodAnalysisNoException(Class<Analysis> analysisClass, Method method) {
        try {
            return getMethodAnalysis(analysisClass, method);
        } catch (CheckedAnalysisException e) {
            IllegalStateException ise = new IllegalStateException("should not happen");
            ise.initCause(e);
            throw ise;
        }
    }

    ....
 }
```

What is the meaning of first `<Analysis>` in the method declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) type. They were [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) in Java 1.5 and allow you to specify additional compile time information which is meant to reduce bugs. It is important to note [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) when you talk about Java Generics, because it is a compile time feature that information is *erased* at runtime, and it is an `Object` (that happens to be of type `Analysis`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some info I wrote about generics in this post: [What does generic type mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437870/what-does-generic-type-mean/22438390#22438390)

In Java, "Generics" are parameters for types. This may sound confusing but here is a simple explanation. If you were making a class that many other classes will inherit from, you want to make it broad and flexible. So you would use a "Generic" type to create instance variables.

Generic types can be implemented as: (Note the diamond brackets "<>")

```
public class TestClass<T>
```

Creating Instances With Generics This may a little more in depth than your question, but I thought I would mention how to create an instance of a generic class.

Note the argument that goes in the diamond braces has to be an object. For primitive types, you can just use Int, Double, Float (with capital first letters) and Java will "auto-box" the objects into primitive types.

```
ClassName<String> obj = new ClassName<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge its a `Bytecode Analysis Framework`. Definitely `Analysis` is a class.
You can find few code sample [here](http://findbugs.googlecode.com/git-history/5061933e51ea8dbc003b29c6b6ebf0b80c08622b/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/ba/ClassContext.java).

```
What is the meaning of first <Analysis> in the method declaration?
```

This type is a generic type of declaration of method.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `< Analysis >` is a very poorly named type variable.  That means the method `getMethodAnalysisNoException` can be called with a parameter of `Class<T>`  for any type `T` and will return an instance of the type `T` if it doesn't throw an unchecked exception.  Usually we don't use type variable names that look like regular class names because it is confusing, as evidenced by the wrong answers several folks have given here.